# Necessary condition for Lie algebra of unitary group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Suppose we have a smooth curve $\alpha$ in U$(n)$, the Lie group of unitary matrices, with $\alpha(0) = I$. Then we have $\alpha(t)^*\alpha(t) = I$. Let $\dot{\alpha}(0) = X$.
I want to show that $\frac{d}{d t}\big{\rvert}_{t = 0}\alpha(t)^*\alpha(t) = X^* + X = 0$.

Now my approach was the following:
For general Lie groups with multiplication map $m$, inversion $i$ and $\Delta(g) = (g,g)$ I know that $dm_{(p,q)}(X,Y) = dR_q X + dL_p Y$, $di_e(X) = -X$ and $d\Delta_p (X) = (X,X)$. Because conjugate transpose is inversion in this example we have $\alpha(t)^*\alpha(t) = I = (m \circ (i,id) \circ \Delta )(\alpha(t))$. I think that applying the chain rule gives

$$ \frac{d}{d t}\bigg{\rvert}_{t = 0}\alpha(t)^*\alpha(t) = 0 = dm_{(I,I)}(di_I X,X) = X- X$$

Where is my mistake or why does this approach not work? (I know that I could use the product rule instead)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the product rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\alpha(t)^*\alpha(t)=\dot{\alpha}(t)^*\alpha(t)+\alpha(t)^*\dot{\alpha}(t).
$$
Then plug in $t=0$ on both sides to get
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\alpha(t)^*\alpha(t)=X^*+X.
$$

Comment: Hm yes, I know that I can use the product rule. But I wanted to understand why my approach does not work.

Comment: Your approach shows that $0=0$, so it is correct. But by using the relation $\alpha(t)^*=\alpha(t)^{-1}$ prematurely, you have skipped the intermediate step to show that $0=X^*+X=0$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, kind of. Need to digest that.

Comment: By the way, when you edited your question to say that you can "use the product rule instead", it is not an alternative, but actually present in both approaches. You are also using the product rule, just you have written it in a more abstract notation that might be adding to your confusion. The product rule is equivalent to your statement that $dm_{(p,q)}(X,Y) = dR_q X + dL_p Y$.

Comment: Well, in some sense this is a product rule aswell. I don't have any confusion with the "euclidean" product rule or the one for Lie groups. I meant instead in the sense that I know to do it the other way: applying the usual product rule, since everything lives in euclidean space.